# Is it possible for matshow() to plot dots or circles instead of squares?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on a simple "game of life" implementation in Python 3, I'm using matplotlib for visualization. And I was wondering if Is it possible for `matshow( )` to plot dots or circles instead of squares? And how to do it if possible.

Example of a typical matshow plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/td1si.png

What i'm looking for: http://blogs.mathworks.com/images/cleve/glider_gun_2.png

Answer (score 0):

You may find an example with code here:
[Matplotlib Gallery, Scatter plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html)

You can provide the code you have generated for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but they are using plt.scatter( ) there, not matshow( ).

Answer (score 0):

Though I did not find anything to change the shape of the squares of matshow, you can use scatter to plot something that you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matrix = np.random.rand(5,6)
#now your points and values are:
nx,ny = matrix.shape
X,Y,values = zip(*[ (i,j,matrix[i,j]) for i in range(nx) for j in range(ny) ] )
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(X,Y,s=5000,c=values,cmap='viridis',alpha=0.5)
```

probably you want a smaller point size but this made the plot look more fancy. 
[image: ![matplotlib scatter as matshow]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWbJ5.png)